# How can I check the existence of tags in XML before parsing using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, elementtree

I'm relatively new to python and currently trying to parse and convert XML to CSV. My code works if the parent and child tags exists, but I receive this error message:

Phone = element[3][0].text
IndexError: child index out of range

when a tag exist in the first attribute but not the second attribute.

I tried to put in an if statement, but it didn't quite work. This is what the xml and my original code looks like. If anyone can point me in the right the direction, I would appreciate it!

XML File

```
        <Member>
        <Person>
          <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
          <LastName>DOE</LastName>
          <Address>
            <Address1>1234 TEST DR</Address1>
            <Address2></Address2>
            <City>SIMCITY</City>
            <State>TD</State>
            <ZipCode>12345    </ZipCode>
          </Address>
          <Phone>
            <AreaCode>212</AreaCode>
            <PhoneNumber>2223333</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <FirstName>JANE</FirstName>
          <LastName>DOE</LastName>
          <Address>
            <Address1>1234 DEE ST</Address1>
            <Address2></Address2>
            <City>LCITY</City>
            <State>TD</State>
            <ZipCode>12345    </ZipCode>
          </Address>
        </Person>
        </Member>
```

My Code:

```
        import  csv
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

        tree = ET.parse("Stack.xml")
        root = tree.getroot()

        xml_data_to_csv =open('Out.csv','w')

        Csv_writer=csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)
        list_head=[]

        count=0
        for element in root.findall('Person'):
            person = []
            address_list = []
            phone_list = []

            #get head node
            if count == 0:
               FirstName = element.find('FirstName').tag
               list_head.append(FirstName)

               LastName = element.find('LastName').tag
               list_head.append(LastName)

               Address = element[2].tag
               list_head.append(Address)

               Phone = element[3].tag
               list_head.append(Phone)

               Csv_writer.writerow(list_head)
               count = count +1

            #get child node
            FirstName = element.find('FirstName').text
            person.append(FirstName)

            LastName = element.find('LastName').text
            person.append(LastName)

            Address = element[2][0].text
            address_list.append(Address)
            Address2 = element[2][1].text
            address_list.append(Address2)
            City = element[2][2].text
            address_list.append(City)
            State = element[2][3].text
            address_list.append(State)
            ZipCode = element[2][4].text
            address_list.append(ZipCode)
            person.append(address_list)

            Phone = element[3][0].text
            phone_list.append(Phone)
            AreaCode = element[3][1].text
            phone_list.append(AreaCode)
            person.append(phone_list)

            #Write List_nodes to csv
            Csv_writer.writerow(person)
        xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [xpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to find the tags you need, for example, you can replace this code:

```
Phone = element[3][0].text
phone_list.append(Phone)
AreaCode = element[3][1].text
phone_list.append(AreaCode)
person.append(phone_list)
```

something like this:

```
phone_list = [e.text for e in element.findall('Phone//')]
person.append(phone_list)
```

or is it (in my opinion the best option):

```
person.append([e.text for e in element.findall('Phone//')])
```

Thus, you will be able to bypass the error and significantly reduce the amount of code :)

Comment: Thanks for the xpath information, but it looks like I get this error message when I replace my code with the options you provided: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 1, column 3

Comment: How can xpath be used to see if the tags are not consistent in the XML file?